# How to skip talking to my husband in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So after I marry any husband in Skyrim (I've tried a few) it tells me to talk to him during the reception. I talk to him and he goes to my house but it shows that I haven't completed that part of the marriage quest. Is there a way to skip it or work around it? I am tired of getting remarried.

Comment: Are you on PC or a console?

Comment: I use PC. I have looked everywhere for an answer.

Comment: You could try using the console, but I'm not sure which marriage quest to change. Maybe see if `SetStage RelationshipMarriageWedding 100` helps... that command is mentioned at [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Bonds_of_Matrimony). Or maybe set the stage to 500 or 1000. I saw those stages in the Creation Kit, but I don't know what they do. Or maybe `SetStage RelationshipMarriageFIN 20`. I don't know what that one does either though...

Comment: I will try and let you know the results.

Comment: i tried the first one and all it did was add a wedding band. And on the second one it said that it was a 'unknown variable 'FIN' for set stage'.

Comment: You just need to tell him that you're tired from a long day of adventuring.  I'm sure he'll understand.

Comment: I think you might have put an extra space before `FIN` on that second command. What is the specific message it's giving you in the quest journal?